# How to find constraint by name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have quite big database (Postgresql 9.3) with plenty of tables, constraints, etc. Some of the tables and constraint are automatically generated (some queries are also automatically generated).

Recently I found out that at some point there is a problem - one of the huge queries violates one constraint.

My question is: how can I easily find a definition of the constraint if I know it's name using SQL?

Comment: `pg_constraint` table by `conname` column; details are [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message contains the constraint that was violated, using that name, you can easily retrieve the definition of that constraint:

e.g. if the constraint that was violated is named `orders_customer_id_fkey` then the following show you that constraint:

```
select pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid, true)
from pg_constraint c
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.connamespace
where conname = 'orders_customer_id_fkey'
and n.nspname = 'public'
```